# Knockout ViewModels

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In knockout can I put a data-bind in to an object that isn't the view model? I am trying to make available to the whole page common settings or theme related values. I don't want to add them to every view model.

i.e. data-bind="MyGlobalSingleton.Prop"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can, but the Property that you are binding to, needs to be a Knockout observable within your object. Otherwise you won't be able to use the benefits of Two-Way binding.

Comment: Thanks ye I guessed that

Answer (score 1):

Knockout's bindings are wrapped in functions that are executed just like any other javascript. Because the bindings are also wrapped in `with` tags, any property you use in a bind will be searched for in:

1. Firstly, in the current context (usually a "viewmodel")
2. Then, in Knockout's own `bindingContext` object (`$data` refers to (1), other handy `$`-prefixed properties like `$parent` are available here)
3. Lastly, in the global namespace. In browsers mostly: `window`

This gives you lots of options in where to store stuff, but you need to be aware of what happens when you re-use property names. Some examples:

```js
window.myProp = "I'm in window";
// We could also use `var notUsedInVM` here because
// this is executed in window scope
window.notUsedInVM = "I'm ONLY in window";

var SubViewModel = function() {
  this.myProp = "I'm in a sub view model";
};

var RootViewModel = function() {
  this.myProp = "I'm in the root view model";

  this.subVM = new SubViewModel();
};

ko.applyBindings(new RootViewModel());
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p>
    Window prop: <strong data-bind="text: window.myProp"></strong>
  </p>
  <p>
    My prop: <strong data-bind="text: myProp"></strong>
  </p>
  <p>
    Sub prop: <strong data-bind="text: subVM.myProp"></strong>
  </p>

  <div data-bind="with: subVM">
   <p>
    Window prop: <strong data-bind="text: window.myProp"></strong>
  </p>
    <p>
    Unique window prop: <strong data-bind="text: notUsedInVM"></strong>
  </p>
  <p>
    My prop: <strong data-bind="text: myProp"></strong>
  </p>
  <p>
    Root prop: <strong data-bind="text: $root.myProp"></strong>
  </p>

  </div>
</div>
```

This means you can easily define a static object in window and access it throughout your nested data-bind contexts, **as long as you do not use the same property name in your viewmodels**.

A safer way might be to either:

- pass (a subset of) settings to the viewmodels in which they are relevant
- store the settings in your root viewmodel and bind to them using `$root.MySettings`